# Can't delete parent of element that had event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="product-template">
<div class='product'>
  <button class='changeProductType'>Change</button>
</div>
```

```
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".container",

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render','changeProductType');

        this.render();
    },

    events: {
        "click .changeProductType": "changeProductType"
    },

    render: function() {
        var source = $('#product-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
    },


    changeProductType: function(ev){
        var removeThis = ev.target.parent();
        //alert(removeThis);

        $("#changeProductTypeModal li a").on('click', function(){
                            removeThis.remove();
            $.modal.close();
        });
    }

});
```

When I alert the ev.target it says "[object HTMLButtonElement]", which is good. But when I try to remove the entire .product div, it doesn't work.

The error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`. So how can I remove the parent element of the button that gets clicked?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: There is no method `parent()` in javascript. You can use $(ev.target).parent()` since you are using jQuery or use `ev.target.parentElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `event.target.parentNode` or `event.target.parentElement` instead of "parent()". I have heard of a method called "parent()" in DOM API.